# Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0 || Flutter || Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am getting this `Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0` when I am trying to load products from firebase documents.
This warning comes after I log in with id password then it comes to the homepage where it loads all the products while loading the products it only shows me circularprogressindicator.

and in console i get this error [image: ERROR]

This same question has been asked twice in stack over flow and I went to each answers and added internet permission and all but nothing worked for me.I even checked my firebase document variable names and matched them with my code but everything was fine.

Comment: I solved the issue.
in my firebase document, one variable was null.
I highly recommend whoever getting the error please check your all variables

Comment: Please post your answer if this is resolved so that other community members will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this description was null before that I was getting this error
I will suggest to all of you who ever getting an error to check all your variable and also cross-check your code.

[image]